# Laravel 8 - search paginate ( withQueryString ) not working on table when searching NUMBERS on row integer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i can't search when it comes to searching NUMBERS on `row int (price)`, but when searching like String number on `row string (name)` it's working fine

like this in my table row here is my **Product table**

```
category_id
"56"
user_id
"1"
name
"555"
description
"fruit"
price
555
```

when i am searching  the `name` row "555" it's working fine beacuse its a `string`. but when it comes to price i can't search it because it's `int`

here is my code for controller searching

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    if($request->search){
        $search = $request->search;
        $products = Products::with('category')
        ->where('name','like',"%$search%")
        ->orWhere('price','like',"%$search%")
        ->where('user_id',$user)->paginate(10);
    }else{
        $products = Products::with('category')->where('user_id',$user)->paginate(10);
    }
      return view('client.product.index',['products'=>$products]);
}
```

here is my blade

```
    <form class="w-full" action="{{ route('client.product.index') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input placeholder="Search"  type="search" name="search">     
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

@foreach ($products as $product)
    <p>{{ $product->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $product->price }}</p>
@endforeach
{{ $products->withQueryString()->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
```

Comment: I really don't think that is a problem. It does not matter if the `$search` variable is an integer or string in php. However, it is strange to search a price with "LIKE".

Comment: i want to search the price also like the name of the product or the name of category. i don't think if LIKE is good proper for searching price.

Comment: I would also look at the use of `where` and `orWhere`. if the name where is false, user id where is true and price orwhere is false, no results will be returned. However if the user id where is false and the price search true, There will be results. I think you need to group the name and price (where and orwhere)

Comment: oh how to group them may i know? i am new for using eloquent or queries on laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the where and orWhere so the user_id will be correctly filtered:

```
 $products = Products::with('category')
    ->where( function($q) use ($search) {
      $q->where('name','like',"%$search%");
      $q->orWhere('price','like',"%$search%");
    })  
    ->where('user_id',$user)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: it gives me error. syntax error, unexpected variable "$q" on where function

Comment: did you see my last adit, i forgot some `;`

Comment: i think this one is good for grouping the where or orwhere groups thank you for sharing i learned a new tricks for this. but still not working when i am searching the price (int).

Comment: maybe on the mongodb is issue for this because i am using. laravel and mongodb

Comment: You could check the $search is numeric and use an if statement so the orWhere is only added if it is numeric. I would change the price check which is strange using LIKE. It could be that mongodb works differently than mysql. that I don't know

Comment: i also tried BETWEEN query.  but still not working. i guess the withquerystring is not working when searching numbers or integer

Comment: Like operator doesn't work with number #2138 @ https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/2138

Comment: oh already working now i used (int)$variable